# bringing xml values into controller then putting in array and passing to view and displaying in highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm bringing in xml data to my application controller, passing to an array and then passing the data stored in this array to the view and into a highchart. Can anyone help please, I've the vast majority of it done, I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
def index

@doc =   Nokogiri::XML(open("http://api.worldbank.org/countries/BRA/indicators/1.0.HCount.2.5usd?per_page=10&date=1960:2014"))
@values = Array.new(9)
for i in 0 .. 8
@values[i] = @doc.xpath('//wb:value')
end
end
```

I then call the data in my series:

```
data: [<%=@values[0]%>, <%=@values[1]%>, <%=@values[2]%>, <%=@values[3]%>, <%=@values[4]%>, <%=@values[5]%>, <%=@values[6]%>, <%=@values[7]%>, <%=@values[8]%>]
```

The error message is as below:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

highlighted area where the error is:

```
data: [<%=@values[0]%>, <%=@values[1]%>, <%=@values[2]%>, <%=@values[3]%>, <%=@values[4]%>, <%=@values[5]%>, <%=@values[6]%>, <%=@values[7]%>, <%=@values[8]%>] –
```

Comment: Could you please also indicate what is the error you are getting?

Comment: The error message is as below:

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

highlighted area where the error is:

 data: [<%=@values[0]%>, <%=@values[1]%>, <%=@values[2]%>, <%=@values[3]%>, <%=@values[4]%>, <%=@values[5]%>, <%=@values[6]%>, <%=@values[7]%>, <%=@values[8]%>]

Answer (score 0):

On line 6, you forgot to indicate `@doc.xpath('//wb:value')`, so it should be:

```
@values[i] = @doc.xpath('//wb:value')
```

`doc` is instance variable.

For the array issue, you could use:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://api.worldbank.org/countries/BRA/indicators/1.0.HCount.2.5usd?per_page=10&date=1960:2014"))
m = @doc.xpath("//wb:value").collect(&:text)
@values = Array.new
m.each do |m|
@values << m
end
```